# Ionic triggers unwanted ng-click on right click and middle click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I am using Ionic in the latest Chrome Version and Chrome canary for some very ODD reason **Right click** causes `ng-click` to trigger.

[Code Pen demonstrating the issue](https://codepen.io/arthurv/pen/bBWLGx)

any one can shed some light ?

Comment: i have never seen like this....

Comment: That's really strange, when you take a look at the event in IE console there's two event, one is a `PointerEvent` where you can detect `which` button of the mouse is clicked. In Chome, there's only a `MouseEvent` where the `which` property always = `1` (left click)

Comment: Ionic is a framework for creating mobile apps. When you're using an app on a mobile phone, there is no left or right click, only a tap.  Because of this, treating left and right clicks the same was probably a design decision.

Comment: add this data-tap-disabled="true" or use on-tap instead on ng-click

Answer (score 0):

Change your Button tag by this,

```
 <button type="button" class="button button-large button-energized" ng-click="test()">click me!!!</button>
```

Or

`<button type="button" class="button button-large button-energized" ng-click="test($event)">click me!!!</button>`

and on your controller:

```
$scope.test = function($event){$event.preventDefault();alert(1);
```

Hope this helps.